# Did any Nazi TV news broadcasts survive?

Tags: nazi-germany, television

According to wikipedia, there was *some* adoption of television in Nazi Germany,

> The first regular electronic television service in Germany began in Berlin on March 22, 1935, as [Deutscher Fernseh Rundfunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutscher_Fernseh-Rundfunk). Broadcasting from the Fernsehsender Paul Nipkow, it used a 180-line system, and **was on air for 90 minutes, three times a week.** Very few receivers were ever privately owned, and viewers went instead to Fernsehstuben (television parlors). During the 1936 Summer Olympics, broadcasts, up to eight hours a day, took place in Berlin and Hamburg.

So from 1935-1944 the Nazis had TV through Deutscher Fernseh Rundfunk. This overlaps with CBS News in the USA (which started in 1941). Did the Nazis ever have anything like prime time broadcast news? And if so, is there any archival footage of it?

Comment: German Wiki has a much more detail. See [Fernsehsender Paul Nipkow](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernsehsender_Paul_Nipkow) for detailed schedules.

Comment: When did the concept of TV newscasts originate? where?

Comment: @MCW In the first years: displaying motion was a problem. Since many of the broadcasters also were radio broadcasters, it would also be a question when it was worth the effort. Showing prepaired films would offer something different than radio. News probably started when timeslots needed to be filled and enough viewers existed to make it worth the effort. When the recording of pictures (video instead of developed film) became possible during the 1950's, then TV news would have become something really different than radio news.

Answer (score 7):

> Did the Nazis ever have anything like prime time broadcast news?

No, there were no daily news broadcasts. What was shown was the, film based, *Wochenschau* (weekly newreels) that was also shown in the cinemas.

> And if so, is there any archival footage of it?

No, the recording technology didn't exist to record the **television camera** input directly.

Most of what you see today, was filmed using a **film camera** and then broadcast.

All broadcasts that were done directly are considered to be lost.

The 11 minute 1935 documentary (see YouTube link below) gives you a good idea how things were done. The documentary itsself was first shown in the weekly newreels in 1935. It also shows how the, later, [public video telephone service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_videotelephony#Closed-circuit_videophone_systems:_1936) worked.

See also: [What time of day was Hitler's opening speech of the 1936 Summer Olympics? - History Stack Exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/68780/38607). The answer is based on the timetable of the television broadcaster.

---

**Sources** (German only):

- [Fernsehsender Paul Nipkow (Programm) – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernsehsender_Paul_Nipkow#Programm)

  - [Rognitzstraße 9, 14057 Berlin](https://maps.app.goo.gl/ZZ799NoZSB4D8Yqs5) (Google Maps)
- [Deutsches Rundfunk-Museum – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsches_Rundfunk-Museum)
- [1935: Das Auge der Welt - Fernsehen leicht erklärt](https://youtu.be/v8c2kxujPOc) (YouTube)

  - The eye of the world - television easily explained
- [History of videotelephony - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_videotelephony#Closed-circuit_videophone_systems:_1936)